# Center an object in BorderPane

Tags: java, javafx

In JavaFX, how to center an object in the top or bottom compartment in BorderPane layout?

I have:

```
borderPane.setBottom(hBox);
```

And hBox appears on the left side of the bottom compartment of BorderPane `borderPane`.And I want it to be in the center of the bottom. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default alignment for borderpane positions are:

```
top: Pos.TOP_LEFT
bottom: Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT
left: Pos.TOP_LEFT
right: Pos.TOP_RIGHT
center: Pos.CENTER
```

To change this for different alignment use:

```
BorderPane.setAlignment(child, Pos.CENTER);
BorderPane.setMargin(child, new Insets(12,12,12,12)); // optional
borderPane.setBottom(child);
```

You may also change the child HBox alignment as:

```
hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

Refer to java API documentation for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. My label I am trying to center is still shown left-aligned.

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt add: BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Alignment method like

```
borderPane.setBottom(hBox);
borderPane.setAlignment(hBox,Pos.CENTER);
```